# How to scale horizontally Amazon RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-rds, autoscaling

How to scale horizontally amazon RDS instance? EC2 and load balancer+autoscaling is extremly easy to implement, but if I want scaling amazon RDS?
I can ugrade my RDS instance with more powerfull instance or I can create a read replica and I can direct SELECT queries to it. But in this mode I don't scale anything if I have a read-oriented web application. So, can I create RDS read replica with autoscaling and balance them with load balancer?

Comment: Goo thinking, not sure what stop you to do that.  http://www.iheavy.com/2012/04/09/autoscaling-mysql-on-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a HAProxy to load-balance Amazon RDS Read Replica's. Check this http://harish11g.blogspot.ro/2013/08/Load-balancing-Amazon-RDS-MySQL-read-replica-slaves-using-HAProxy.html.
Hope this  helps.

Answer (score 3):

Note RDS covers several database engines- mysql, postgresql, Oracle, MSSQL.

Generally speaking, you can scale up (larger instance), use readonly databases, or shard. If you are using mysql, look at AWS Aurora. Think about using the database optimally- perhaps combining with memcached or Redis (both available under AWS Elasticache). Think about using a search engine (lucene, elasticsearch, cloudsearch).

Some general resources:

- http://highscalability.com/
- https://gigaom.com/2011/12/06/facebook-shares-some-secrets-on-making-mysql-scale/

Comment: thanks, I'm using mysql. 
I understood than autoscaler and loadbalancing is not supported for RDS instances. I think I will use memcached+readonly-db. it should be enough :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PostgreSQL and have a workload that can be partitioned by a certain key and doesn't require complex transactions, then you could take a look at the [pg_shard](https://www.citusdata.com/citus-products/pg-shard) extension. pg_shard lets you create distributed tables that are sharded across multiple servers. Queries on the distributed table will be transparently routed to the right shard.

Even though RDS doesn't have the pg_shard extension installed, you can set up one or PostgreSQL servers on EC2 with the pg_shard extension and use RDS nodes as worker nodes. The pg_shard node only needs to store a tiny bit of metadata which can be backed up in one of the worker nodes, so they are relatively low maintenance and can be scaled out to accommodate higher query rates.

A guide with a link to a CloudFormation template to set everything up automatically is available at: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/14-marco/178-scaling-out-postgresql-on-amazon-rds-using-masterless-pg-shard